# Using a scope to access a unique single record without having to loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model `Enrollment` which validates the uniqueness for each course by user:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :course_id
```

I created a scope in the `Enrollment` model where I can pass in the course to narrow down the course by user:

```
scope :course, lambda { |course| where(:course_id => course.id) }
```

By doing this, I can call:

```
current_user.enrollments.course(@course)
```

However, it then makes me loop through the result, even though there is only one result (unique course for each user). This is fine, but it seems like there should be a way to simply do the scope and then just access the record without need to loop through one result.

Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
current_user.enrollments.course(@course).first
```

That will generate SQL query with `LIMIT 1` statement and return the model directly without wrapping it into an array.

Small note about your scope. As your `Enrollment` model has `course` association (`has_one :course` I assume) you'd better give your scope different name like `by_course` to prevent collision with `course` association that allows you to fetch course for a given enrollment.

Comment: Thanks is more human, but upvoting and accepting correct answer is more efficient on StackOverflow =)